# Constraints on Type Parameters - get value from dictionary based on type

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

Code:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, IObserverComponent> _components;
public static T Get<T>()
        where T : Type
    {
        return _components[T] as T;
    }
```

How can I make that work? It says: 'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `typeof(T)` to make it work.

```
public static T Get<T>()  where T : Type
{
    return _components[typeof(T)] as T;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, so simple... How could I miss that... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`_component[someKey]` returns `IObserverComponent` so how can you have your method return T?

shouldn't your method be something like this?

```
public static IObserverComponent Get<T>()
        where T : Type
{
    return _components[typeof(T)];
}
```

Comment: @LexRema but still, the return type wouldn't be T, right? if IObserverComponent and Type aren't related, the `as` operator would just return a null at runtime.